# How to refresh page in the SE Android app?

Tags: support, android-app

I can not figure out how to refresh a page in my SE Android app, v1.0.89. I have Android version 7.0 on a OnePlus 3 smartphone.

Researching this, I found many SE questions and answers talking about "pull to refresh". As I understand it, that means putting your finger on the app title bar, sliding down slightly, and releasing. When I do that, nothing happens.  The title bar does not even move. Do I misunderstand how to use "pull to refresh"? If so, how do I do it properly?  If not, what is the proper refresh method?

A related issue, which led to this one, was the vague permanency of a page update after editing a post. I made a slight edit to an answer of mine, using my smartphone. After submitting it, the change was there. I happened to flip my phone sidewise, which forced a reformat. In the reformatted text, the change was absent. I flipped the phone back upright, and the change was still gone. Since I could not figure out how to do an actual page refresh, I quit the app and restarted it. Going back to the page, I saw that my edit had indeed been made permanent. I wouldn't classify this as a "bug" -- the confused buffers are more of an inconvenience, really. So long as I was posting anyway, it seems worth mentioning.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, anywhere **but** the app title bar would work.

The steps are:

1. Put your finger anywhere on the screen, below the app title bar. (personally prefer on the post body, you can also do it with the question title.)
2. Pull the finger down. Speed doesn't matter, it can be slow and it can be fast.
3. A blue-ish circle will appear, with an arrow forming as you pull down.
4. Pull until the arrow is fully blue and release. (if you release before that, it won't do anything.)
5. Question will refresh.

Also found a [demo on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uEiX11SBzxc), though with different design.

Comment: Thank you, SW -- it works!  However, speed of starting the downward motion does seem to matter, at least in some spots.  At first I did not think it was working, trying your preferred method of finger on post body.  I kept getting the [Copy Share] requester and no blue circle.  Eventually I realized if downward motion begins right away, you can get the refresh wheel every time. Also, the page must already be scrolled all the way up, else your finger will drag the page body down. But now that I know about those issues, it is a feature I can confidently use.

Comment: hmm.. interesting. Maybe you pushed on text, which triggered something else. Glad it worked!